# inserting values to new table in mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Okay guys, I will try to share my guestion understandable. So I have 2 tables like below:
ALL Id from TABLES are Autoincrement.

```
Number

id  number

10   100
11   102
12   105
13   106

subnumber

id  number_id   subnumber

52     10           10
53     11           15
54     13           40
```

You see some numbers (not all) have subnumbers. I mean:
From table `number` the number where id = 13 has subnumber and it is equal to 40. 
I want to save this table in another table.

```
$sql1=mysql_query('SELECT number FROM number');


$while(fetch1=mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
{
   mysql_query('
   INSERT INTO `save_number` (number)'
   VALUES ('.$fetch1['number'].');
   );
}


save_number

id      number
100      100
101      102
102      105  
103      106
```

Now i gonna save table (subnumber) in another table (save_subnumber)

```
$sql2=mysql_query('SELECT number_id, subnumber FROM subnumber');

$while(fetch2=mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
{
   mysql_query('
   INSERT INTO `save_subnumber` (number_id, subnumber)'
   VALUES ('.$fetch2['number_id'].', '.$fetch2['number'].');
   );
}

save_subnumber

id  number_id   subnumber
60     10           10
61     11           15
62     13           40
```

So, you see the number_id FROM save_subnumber is not equal to new inserted id FROM save_number. I would be appreaciated if anyone help me. By the way I am still using mysql_query. I can not find time to improve my SQL to PDO :)

Comment: but it is possible do it in mysql.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? If you are trying to link save_number to number, you need to have a number_id in that table as well, or are you linking based on the actual number? What should save_subnumber actually be storing? the id from save_number as number_id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first query can be changed to

```
INSERT INTO
  save_number (number)
SELECT
  number
FROM 
  number
```

This will save you using PHP to iterate through rows and will be faster. A lot.

Having this in mind your second query would be

```
INSERT INTO
  save_subnumber (number_id, subnumber)
SELECT DISTINCT
  sn.id, s.subnumber
FROM
  saved_number AS sn
CROSS JOIN
   number AS n
USING (number)
INNER JOIN
  subnumber AS s
ON
  n.id = s.number_id
```

Comment: Man, at the last line there is something wrong. there is not number_id   in sn (save_number)

Comment: It's suppposed to be `s.number_id`

Comment: If the count of number>1 then  the count of subnumber equal to count of number * 2
How to fix it?

Comment: Try using SELECT DISTINCT

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to copy one table in another why don't you use something like this

```
INSERT INTO save_number SELECT * FROM number;
```